# springboot Multiple Dockets with the same group name are not supported

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I have the follwoing spring boot configuration for swagger, when service starts up i get the following error, im not sure exactly why this would be the case. I have followed a tutorial and it works for them.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple Dockets with the same group name are not supported. The following duplicate groups were discovered. default


@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
public class SpringFoxConfig {

  @Bean
  public Docket apiDocket() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("test.rest"))
      .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/test/**"))
      .build()
      .apiInfo(apiInfo());
  }

  // Describe the apis
  private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
      .title("test")
      .description("Test")
      .version("1.0.0")
      .license("vvv")
      .build();
  }

}
```

i also have another config

```
@OurApp
@EnableSwagger2
public class CoreApp extends OurApp {

}
```

Comment: well by adding a group name to this i fixed it...

Answer (score 10):

Here you are trying to do multiple Dockets with the same group name, which is not acceptable. Please review the link provided.

> groupName(java.lang.String groupName) If more than one instance of
>   Docket exists, each one must have a unique groupName as supplied by
>   this method. [Documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#groupName(java.lang.String))

```java
public class Docket implements DocumentationPlugin {
        public static final String DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME = "default"; 
}
```

You can see above DocumentPlugin has groupname as "default".

```java
public Docket(DocumentationType documentationType) {
        this.apiInfo = ApiInfo.DEFAULT;
        this.groupName = "default";
```

And above has "default" as group name.

So, you need to have two different group names for both the Dockets.

All you need to do is change your code as below: overwrite the existing default groupname.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class)
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        String groupName = "Swagger";
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("test.rest"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/test/**"))
                .build()
                .groupName(groupName)
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    // Describe the apis
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("test")
                .description("Test")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .license("vvv")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can actually set the ```new Docket(..).groupName()```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have given the same group name which is not accepted, please check and set the group name properly.